# Make Schema changes to SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm currently using SQL Server Compact edition. I am using CompactViewer to access the database. CompactViewer allows me to make data changes but it does not seem to allow schema changes. I am using EF code-first if it makes any difference, but I would like the ability to make schema changes manually.

Has anyone been able to use CompactViewer to make schema changes? Otherwise, is there another tool/another way to make schema changes to a SQL Server Compact database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make schema changes with my "SQL Server Compact Toolbox" Visual Studio extension and standalone app.